mysql 5.7 on Ubuntu 20.04. Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
I have quite a bunch of MyISAM tables for which I installed MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 20.04. 8.0 desn't handle MyISAM and, to my knowledge, a translator MySQL to InnoDB is not available. So I recently did a full upgrade and lost access to the 'mysql' server. Sure enough the upgrade had installed 8.0. So I removed 8.0 and reinstalled 5.7, completing error-free. 'Synaptic' confirms the correct installation and 'ps' confirms the server process. So far so good. Next I should reset the passwords:
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
This is what it says:
Enter password for user root: ...
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock (111)'
'ls' confirms '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists.
Posts on unconnectable 'mysql.sock' abound. One of them explains the complete removal of absolutely everything to do with 'mysql'. That might be my last resort. However, that seems like a massive overkill when the solution seems only a tweak away, obvious to someone who knows the inner workings better than I do. Of course the simplest solution would by to find a tool for translating MyISAM to InnoDB or to any other widely used industry standard.

Thanks for the guidance. Here is what "lsof" says:
:~$ lsof -p 1473
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD  TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  1473 mysql  cwd  unknown /proc/1473/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
mysqld  1473 mysql  rtd  unknown /proc/1473/root (readlink: Permission denied)
mysqld  1473 mysql  txt  unknown /proc/1473/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
mysqld  1473 mysql NOFD          /proc/1473/fd (opendir: Permission denied)

And these are all configuration files. (Out of the box. My modest understanding of the system would make editing configuration files a rather adventurous endeavor.)
-:~$ for name in $(sudo find /etc -name '*mysql*.cnf')
>      do echo ========================================================================== echo
>      echo $name; echo
>      echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------; echo
>      cat $name
>      echo
>      done
==========================================================================

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

#
# The MySQL database client configuration file
#
# Ref to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/mysql-command-options.html

[mysql]

==========================================================================

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

[mysqld_safe]
syslog

==========================================================================

/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_open_cache       = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log     = 1
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

==========================================================================

/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

==========================================================================

/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

==========================================================================

/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

[mysql]

==========================================================================


It is not an answer. It is added info. I am the OP. I published the contents of all mysql .cnf files, in the hope that a superior intelligence might identify a possible cause of the unconnectability of '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock', and, or, suggest a remedial edit of one or the other .cnf file.
Harkening back to the first respondent, Sleepyhead, who said: "...the process should also connect to the socket. Is it listed on lsof -p [pid] ?" I showed the output, which, called without 'sudo', was of no use. So I redo: 'sudo lsof -p 1567'. Makes 88 lines, mostly data files. Grepping for 'sock', 'localhost' and 'mysqld' I get:
:~$ sudo lsof -p 1567 | grep -E "sock|localhost|mysqld(\.|$)"

lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse file system /run/user/1001/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
mysqld  1567 mysql  txt    REG              259,3 24890376 10487830 /usr/sbin/mysqld
mysqld  1567 mysql    4u  unix 0xffff8e0918278000      0t0    77653 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type=STREAM
mysqld  1567 mysql   27u  IPv4              49147      0t0      TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)
mysqld  1567 mysql   28u  unix 0xffff8e091c092640      0t0    49148 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type=STREAM
mysqld  1567 mysql   44u  unix 0xffff8e091827ea40      0t0    77659 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type=STREAM
mysqld  1567 mysql   46u  unix 0xffff8e091827d940      0t0    77660 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type=STREAM
mysqld  1567 mysql   47u  unix 0xffff8e0918279dc0      0t0    77651 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type=STREAM
mysqld  1567 mysql   48u  unix 0xffff8e091827f700      0t0    77652 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type=STREAM
mysqld  1567 mysql   51u  unix 0xffff8e091827f2c0      0t0    77654 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type=STREAM
mysqld  1567 mysql   52u  unix 0xffff8e091827cc80      0t0    77655 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type=STREAM
mysqld  1567 mysql   54u  unix 0xffff8e091827d0c0      0t0    77656 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type=STREAM
mysqld  1567 mysql   55u  unix 0xffff8e0918278440      0t0    77657 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type=STREAM
mysqld  1567 mysql   56u  unix 0xffff8e091827c840      0t0    77658 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type=STREAM

The server seems to be running (mysqld). 'mysql' seems to be listening on 'localhost'. Could that be the mistake? Should it not be listening on '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'?

You did the ps, does it show that mysqld is listening on the socket, or is it listening on the network interfaces only. The socket file can exist, but the process should also connect to the socket. Is it listed on lsof -p [pid] ? you can configure it in a file named something like /etc/mysqld/my.cnf
